# Prevent weapon from clipping during animations

Tags: unity, animation

I am trying my ways with Unity 3d animations, and so far so good.

The only problem is, when I equip an weapon in the player model's hand, the weapon clip through player's head during some frames of some animations. Please refer to the gif and the screenshot below for an example.

[image: Bow clipping through player head]

Here you can see that the top of the bow is clipping through the player head during the arrow fire animation.

[image]

Here you can see a demonstration gif of the problem.

I've been thinking and I will probably need to adjust the weapon rotation/position so it fits the animations, right?

Comment: I would rather look into the animations of the character model and see how I can design them in a way which leaves more space for the equipment. When you have characters with deformed proportions, you need to design your animations in a way which accounts for those proportions. The physique of a character affects the way it moves. Your characters look super cute, even without textures. But they are simply physically unable to perform the same motions a character with realistic proportions could perform, at least not in the same way.

Comment: @Philipp So the problem is basically that the animations need to be adjusted for the deformed proportions of the character, and not that I am missing some kind of configuration, right?

Comment: Please consider using a screen recording tool to record your animations as videos or gifs, rather than an unsteady handheld camera.

Comment: @Arturthetemplar Yes, if you just retargeted an animation designed for a different character, then you might want to redo it. Animation retargeting generally only gives you good results for characters with very similar proportions. When the characters are too different, you migth want to redo their animations from scratch.

Comment: @Philipp Fair enough. If you want to write an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your characters have very deformed proportions. It seems like you took an animation designed for a character with more realistic proportions and retargeted it. Animation retargeting generally only gives you good results for characters with very similar proportions. When the characters are too different, then you usually get better results if you redo their animations from scratch.

When you have characters with deformed proportions, you need to design your animations in a way which accounts for those proportions. The physique of a character affects the way it moves. Your characters look super cute, even without textures. But they are simply physically unable to perform the same motions a character with realistic proportions could perform, at least not in the same way.

And even if some animations sort of work without clipping, they might not necessarily be appropriate for the general look and feel of the character. Animating chibi-characters can be a lot of fun, because you can really exaggerate their motions and body language. And it would be a shame to not make any use of this creative potential.

I am looking forward to playing with those characters in their finished form.

Answer (score 0):

This works in some cases:

- You can modify the weight of bones that rotate too much by changing the animation layer Weight at the time where your problematic animations start and reset it back to 1 when you go back to animations that works with no problem
- You can also configure your avatar to set limits to rotations of bones that cause the clipping